UBUNTU Partition locked after run out of space
I am using ubuntu 20.22 installed on SSD driver with 250 GB.
Last month my driver run out of space, and later on the partition was locked.
I tried to use a usb-driver to reinstall ubuntu (Try ubuntu without installing option), but it does not identify the locked partition. Using gparted, I does not locate the main partition that is locked:
root@ubuntu:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.2 GiB, 2409508864 bytes, 4706072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 32.3 MiB, 33869824 bytes, 66152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 55.4 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 61.8 MiB, 64770048 bytes, 126504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 65.1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 241.4 MiB, 253087744 bytes, 494312 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 2.5 MiB, 2605056 bytes, 5088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 3.8 GiB, 4037017600 bytes, 7884800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4c050c47

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          0 4910399 4910400  2.3G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2       4840192 4844991    4800  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disk /dev/loop8: 704 KiB, 720896 bytes, 1408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

All I get is this busybox screen:
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=xxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30 (Ubuntu x) built-in shell (ash)xx
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)_

Using:
(initramfs) cat /proc/modules
I get the attached image output:

I've tried to follow some steps proposed by other forums like this one:
1-Enter reboot in the prompt
2-Goto BIOS setup
3-Goto SATA Configuration
4-Change to AHCI
5-save and restart.

But my F12 screen does not allow to change SATA configuration (frozen option)



Is drive still shown in UEFI/BIOS? Your fdisk only shows the snaps(loops) and flash drive. You can list drives without snaps with lsblk -e 7 -f The -e 7 excludes the loops.

I updated my question with your requests. The SSD driver, should contains 250 gb with ubuntu installed on that.

Your 18.04 is obsolete and not supported here. You need to use a current version even for repairs. You are showing SATA mode with Intel RST & Optane. Optane is also obsolete and most booting with Ubuntu turn off or even totally remove Optane.  HP Spectre x360 15t  Optane issue
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474790 &
https://chanon.info/install-ubuntu-22.04-on-hp-envy-x360/

You are right. 18.04 is not useful even for repairs.
It worked. Tks a lot
